# Definitive list of protocols supported by the WebClient and WebRequest classes

Tags: .net

The docs state:

From [WebRequest.Create Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx)

> The .NET Framework includes support for the http://, https://, and file:// URI schemes. Custom  WebRequest descendants to handle other requests are registered with the  RegisterPrefix method.

However I've also been using this class to get files via ftp (not listed in the docs). Is there a definitive list of supported protocols documented anywhere?

UPDATE: To clarify. Yes additional protocols can be plugged-in, but what is the standard/baseline set of protocols supported in the class framework assuming I haven't registered any others. e.g. sftp, tftp?

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be a definitive list. As the article says,

> Custom WebRequest descendants to
>   handle other requests are registered
>   with the RegisterPrefix method.

This means that anyone can create a foo:// prefix if they like, so your code should make as few assumptions as possible about the protocol in use.

Answer (score 0):

The Default List contains exactly these four Protocols as of 2022: "https:","http:","file:","ftp:"
Check it using the following NUnit Test, which uses Reflection to retrieve this (otherwise hidden) Details:

```cs
    [TestCase(ExpectedResult = new [] {"https:","http:","file:","ftp:"})]
    public static object TestSupportedProtocols() {
        var property = typeof(WebRequest).GetProperty("PrefixList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        var value = property.GetValue(null, null);
        var list = value as IList;
        var fieldInfo = list[0].GetType().GetField("Prefix");
        var values = list.OfType<object>().Select(d => fieldInfo.GetValue(d)).ToList();
        return values;
    }
```

Since these are Implementation Details, the List of Protocols and this Code may not work in future Versions.